# Is it possible to update one collection using joins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections with the following schemas

```
var document = new TestDocAccess({
  documentId: '50dc37d6022b2bdd07000004',
  userId : "1234",
  userName : "Test Name",
  identifier : [String]
});
```

and

```
var master = new TestDocMaster({
  documentId: document._id,
  masterId: "50a5e7bcda3c4d557f00847a"
});
```

Is there anyway to update the fields in the `documents` collection with the `masterId` from the `master` collection.

Answer (score 2):

Any "joins" made in a document-based database like MongoDB has to be made in your application. So basically you would have to first query for the id from the `master collection` and then use that id to update the correct document in the `documents collection`.